# Could SLURM trigger a script(implemented by the frontend-SLURM user) when any job is completed?

Tags: slurm

As we know SLURM can sent a e-mail when a job is completed.

In addition to that, similar to mailing mechanism when job is completed:

[Q] Could SLURM trigger a script(implemented by the frontend-SLURM user) when any job is completed?

Example solution: This would force me to have while() to check and wait is the submitted job is completed. This might eat additional CPU usage.

```
jobID=$(sbatch -U user -N1 run.sh | cut -d " " -f4-);
job_state=$(sacct -j $jobID --format=state  | tail -n1 | head -n1)
while [ $job_state != $completed ]
do
    job_state=$(sacct -j $jobID --format=state  | tail -n1 | head -n1)
done
my_script.sh//When any job completed I want SLURM to trigger my_script.sh if possible.
```

Please that that: I have been told that doing while check each 1 second might be inefficient. [Is doing `while ps -p $PID; do sleep 1; ` until a script is completed efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43675678/2402577)

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: Can't you simply call that script as the last operation in your submission script, using SSH to the frontend if necessary?

Comment: I am trying to make a automated system where when a job is completed, I want to trigger a code right away to allow client to access the results. Please not that client only submits his job externally (he can't do ssh to frontend), so cluster has to let now the client when his job is completed. @damienfrancois

Comment: Have looked at workflow systems such as [Fireworks](https://pythonhosted.org/FireWorks/) or portals such as5slurm-web](http://edf-hpc.github.io/slurm-web/) ? They might do what you need?

Comment: To most simple solution I come up with is to manipulate user's code beginning and ending session with the script I would like to call. @damienfrancois

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be to (ab)use the `MailProg` option in `slurm.conf`. It is initially meant to be the fully qualified path of a program used to send emails upon job completion to the users. But that program can do anything else. It receives the job ID and some other information through the command line arguments.

So you could configure slurm with `MailProg=/path/to/my_script.sh`. And you need to make sure the client adds the `--mail-type` option, or that it is added automatically through a job submit plugin.

The script could have the following structure (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash

# First to the wanted behaviour
jobid=$(echo $2 | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d' ' -f 1|cut -d_ -f1)
event=$(echo $2 | awk 'print $4')

case $event in
Started)
    job_startup_script $jobid 
    ;; 
Ended|Failed|TIMEOUT)
    job_end_script $jobid
    ;; 
esac

# Then send the email to get the usual behaviour
/bin/mail "$@"
```

The script will receive from Slurm arguments looking like this:

```
SLURM Job_id=<Job-ID> Name=<JobName> <Status>, Run time <RunTime>
```

If the script `job_startup_script` is very long, start it with  `nohup` and use the ampersand (`&`) to make it a background process.

Also make sure all the scripts are readable and executable by `SlurmUser`

Comment: If this works, it will be huge help. So would slurm able to trigger the `/path/to/my_script.sh` via mail? For example what should I do to trigger `script_start.sh` on the beginning of the program and `script_end.sh` on the end of program? I guess mail has `STAR`T and `END` parameters. @damienfrancois

Comment: When this script is called on start, and assume it does 1 hour sleep. Does original slurm script wait this called script(my)script) to be completed or SLURM call this script just as a thread and does not wait until it get completed. @damienfrancois

Comment: I assume it does not wait for it, but that is how I would implement it, not sure what the code exactly does. Does your `job_startup_script ` runs for that long?

Comment: Yes it may even run longer :( I wasn't able to integrate mailing to SLURM so I was not able to test it. On conf: `Default:MailProg=/bin/mail`. And my mailing from terminal also works: `echo "Your message" | mail -s "Message Subject" blabla@gmail.com`.  @damienfrancois

Comment: This does not rely on the mailing stuff, it replaces it. If you furthermore need the mailing, add it to the `my_script`.

Comment: If the `job_startup_script` script is very long, run it with `nohup` in the background (with `&`) so that it keeps running even if `my_script` terminates.

Comment: Job should be submitted with `#SBATCH --mail-type=START` and `#SBATCH --mail-type=END` right? I basically I can run `job_startup_script $jobid` as: `nohup job_startup_script $jobid &` But since it get called via SLURM, I cannot send some parameters I want to. Can't I just put nohup to the beginning of `my_script` @damienfrancois

Comment: `--mail-type=ALL`.  //  what kind of parameter would you like to give it? //  I do not think you can put nohup at the beginning of `my_script`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143401/discussion-between-avatar-and-damienfrancois).

Comment: Can I also catch the event when the job is cancelled? all variables return empty string @damienfrancois

Comment: Yes `$event`should then contain `CANCELLED` (from my memory). If all variables `$jobid`, $event`return empty strings, just print the whole line `echo "$@"` to debug.

Comment: @damienfrancois can you please also take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710211/nohup-makes-echo-useless?noredirect=1#comment1344802_710211)