# External user call won't able to run IPFS call

Tags: linux, permissions, slurm, ipfs

I have followed this guide: [Could SLURM trigger a script(implemented by the frontend-SLURM user) when any job is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43777884/2402577) When the job stared on slurm, it triggers a script that I have implemented.

I have the following script. It readable and executable by the SlurmUser. Inside script I want to call [ipfs](https://ipfs.io) and return the hashes that are generated.

hello.sh

```
#!/bin/bash    
export IPFS_PATH="path/to/ipfs_repo/.ipfs"
x=$(/usr/local/bin/ipfs add -r path/to/added)
```

Updated this line on the `slurm.conf`.

```
MailProg=/path/to/my_script.sh
```

So when I run a job through SLURM, this script is able to be triggered. But it won't able to run the `ipfs add -r path/to/added` command so it won't able to return a valid hash. IPFS should writes files on the current path into .ipfs folder and return a hash.

I did:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ipfs
sudo chmod +x path/to/added/*

netlab@ebloc:~/.ipfs$ ls -ls
total 16
4 drwxr-xr-x 78 netlab netlab 4096 May  6 12:02 blocks
4 -rwxr-xr-x  1 netlab netlab 3705 May  5 12:14 config
4 drwxr-xr-x  2 netlab netlab 4096 May  6 12:02 datastore
4 -rwxr-xr-x  1 netlab netlab    2 May  5 12:14 version
```

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the full path of the *ipfs* binary in *hello.sh* as the *PATH* environment variable might be missing the %GOPATH%/bin directory.

Also, IPFS derives its repository's path from the *HOME* enviroment variable. If the *HOME* environment variable is not set or points to a home directory with no initialized IPFS repo, then it won't find an initialized repository, and it will exit with an error. To override the derived path, set the *IPFS_PATH* environment variable before calling the ipfs binary:
export IPFS_PATH=/path/to/ipfsrepo

Comment: `export IPFS_PATH="path/to/ipfs_repo/.ipfs"` fixed it. Thank a lot sir! @Tarnay Kálmán